# Cannot capture reference in lambda from universal reference?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, forwarding-reference

I am trying to figure out why the captured variable cannot be passed to the foo function by reference, the program shown below does not compile with the following error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 
'Object&' from expression of type 'const Object'
```

Is there some way to perfect forward the universal reference into the lambda so that it is captured by reference for later use? Types T might also be R-Values or a combination of R-Values and L-Values, so they cannot always be captured by reference.

```
struct Object
{
};

void foo(Object& a)
{
}

template<typename... T>
auto bar(T&&... values)
{
    return [values...](){
        foo(values...);
    };
}

int main ()
{
    Object obj;
    auto lambda = bar(obj);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're by capturing by values which stores values as const members inside the closure, and they cannot bind to non-const lvalue references. For capture by-ref you've forgot to put '&' before values:

```
return [&values...](){
    foo(values...);
};
```

A small example.

The only diff between the two files:

```
diff omg.cpp nyan.cpp 
6c6
<   return [values...]{ foo(values...); };
---
>   return [&values...]{ foo(values...); };
```

Compile the one with by-value capture:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 omg.cpp && ./a.out 
omg.cpp: In instantiation of ‘bar(T&& ...)::<lambda()> [with T = {int&}]’:
omg.cpp:6:16:   required from ‘struct bar(T&& ...) [with T = {int&}]::<lambda()>’
omg.cpp:6:38:   required from ‘auto bar(T&& ...) [with T = {int&}]’
omg.cpp:11:16:   required from here
omg.cpp:6:25: error: binding reference of type ‘int&’ to ‘const int’ discards qualifiers
  return [values...]{ foo(values...); };
                  ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
omg.cpp:3:6: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void foo(int&)’
 void foo(int &a) { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
  ^~~
```

Compile the other:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 nyan.cpp && ./a.out 
42
314
```

Comment: But if I would capture by reference I might capture temporary R-Values which will result in a crash later. Is there someway to capture by perfect forwarding?

Comment: IIRC, capture-init was introduced in C++14.

Comment: It's not clear how you expect perfect forwarding to save a reference from becoming dangling. If you bind function's argument to a non-const lvalue ref later, you should have it to refer to a live object, eh?